# Pythonic Solution to Multiple Checks

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code:

```
var = foo()
if var:
    return var

var = bar()
if var:
    return var

var = baz()
if var:
    return var
```

Is there a more Pythonic approach to solve this problem?  A good use case for something like this would be retrieving a user setting.  If the user has a specific setting for a screen type then use it.  If not, try to get the user's account-wide screen type and use it.  If not, use a system-wide generic screen type.

Obviously this case is small and would probably be ok.  Suppose I have over 100 "cases" to check in the priority list.  I think we could all agree that could get ridiculous.

Edit:
Sorry if this appears to be a XY question.  In a way, it is I suppose.  This is 100% an academic thought exercise.  I don't actually have a specific use case for this.  It's just something I was thinking about last night and was wondering what the most Pythonic approach would be.

Comment: I can not imagine how there can be 100 different sources for screen settings.

Comment: What on earth are you doing where you check if 100 different functions return a value

Comment: This is a hypothetical situation.  Suppose for the sake of the "Pythonic" discussion there are 100 cases.  Don't get caught up on the example given.

Comment: What cases? What is the logic of each? This sounds like a XY question.

Comment: The logic of any of the `foo`, `bar` and `baz` could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think user161151's solution is good, but if you prefer to maintain dozens or even 100 functions, you could do something like this:

```
lst = [foo, bar, baz, ...]  # add to this list
for func in lst:
    v = func()
    if v:
        return v
```

Answer (score 4):

`return foo() or bar() or baz()` should do it.

Comment: For 100 cases?  I think not.

Comment: His solution is right -- but if you'd prefer to simplify the coding, you can toss the functions into a list of functions, and iterate over each.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the functions and take the first one that returns a boolean `True`:

`var = next(filter(None, (fn() for fn in (foo, bar, baz))))`

*Edit*: this crashed for me when I tested it, and then I realized that in Python 2.x filter returns a list, whereas in Python 3.x filter returns a generator. For a Python 2.x example, see below:

```
def f1():
    print 'called f1'
    return False

def f2():
    print 'called f2'
    return None

def f3():
    print 'called f3'
    return 'yay'

def f4():
    print 'called f4'
    return 'yay1'

from itertools import ifilter

var = next(ifilter(None, (fn() for fn in (f1, f2, f3, f4))))
print var
```

This outputs:

```
called f1
called f2
called f3
yay
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in [foo, bar, baz]:
    t = f()
    if t:
        return t
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of functions could grow unbounded, I'd probably do something like:

```
functions = [
    foo,
    bar,
    baz
]

for fn in functions:
    var = fn()
    if var:
        return var

# some sort of error handling maybe?
```